# Kerberized NFSv4 on Linux Systems

Tags: cron, kerberos, nfs

Forgive me if this question is somewhat incorrect as we are just getting started with NFSv4.

It seems that [kerberized] NFSv4 is well suited for things like home directories that can be authenticated and mounted when a user accesses the system. However, we are considering a few issues and are wondering what the recommended configuration is:

1) Users execute a long running job (assume longer than the Kerberos ticket lifetime) and log out. How can the Kerberos ticket automatically be renewed so that these types of jobs continue to run?
2) How would CRON jobs executing scripts from an NFS share gain a Kerberos ticket to be able to perform these actions?
3) How would local application/service accounts access scripts/files on an NFSv4 share?

Comment: 1) read the manual about `sssd.conf` and espcially `krb5_renew_interval`

Comment: 2) 3) define a private ticket cache with env variable `KRB5CCNAME` (type `KEYRING` for instance, cf. https://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-1.15/doc/basic/ccache_def.html), and impersonate a Kerberos "generic" principal with `kinit -kt /path/to/keytab_with_password dummy_principal@REALM`